# Adding div element to td dynamically

Tags: html, devexpress

I have a `devexpress` grid on a page. I need to add a `div` element with a css class name dynamically at runtime.

I have tried this way:

```
settings.Columns.Add(column =>
        {
            column.Caption = LanguageService.Instance.Translate("Tab_Documents");
            column.FieldName = "DocumentType";
            column.Width = Unit.Pixel(50);
            column.DataItemTemplate = new DivTemplate();
        });
```

and the `DivTemplate`:

```
class DivTemplate : ITemplate
{
    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl NewDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        NewDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "container");
        container.Controls.Add(NewDiv);
    }
}
```

This solution is not adding the div to my td

[image]

I need that the Documents column data to be in a `div`
[image]

Can you please advise?